# matplotlib fails to import

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to import matplotlib in python using the following command
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

However I keep getting the error below. What might be the issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/Documents/vscode/python/scripts/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 66, in <module>

    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, FigureBase, figaspect
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 43, in <module>

    from matplotlib import _blocking_input, backend_bases, _docstring, projections
  File "/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>

    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .axes3d import Axes3D

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, docstring, _preprocess_data
ImportError: cannot import name 'docstring' from 'matplotlib' (/home/mbayi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py)
```

I was trying to import the python matplotlib however the process fails.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: This Github issue seems relevant: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26827